# How can I maximize the number of cantrips for an Eldritch Knight?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, eldritch-knight

An eldritch knight only gets 2 cantrips to start.  This is very limiting. Is there a way to get more cantrips to increase the eldritch knight's utility and flexibility?  What is the maximum number of cantrips possible for a character that is a level 4 eldritch knight?

Comment: @Christopher We have a strict policy of not guessing the system, no matter how obvious it may seem. You can discuss that policy [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9805/3548).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a single class Eldritch Knight (EK) for base of 2 cantrips.

Start as a High Elf for +2 dex, +1 int, and any cantrip from the wizards list. This is more optimal for an EK than starting as a Tiefling.

At level 4 select the Magic Initiate feat to gain 2 cantrips and 1 first level spell.

For a total of 5 cantrips at level 4 plus a bonus spell from magic initiate.

Answer (score 2):

## Multi-classing, feats, and racial features will get you more cantrips.

Being a tiefling grants the cantrip thaumaturgy.  On top of that, taking a level in other classes that grant cantrips or taking the magic initiate feat are the most efficient methods of gaining additional cantrips.

### Max cantrips for a character level 4 with all levels in fighter

A tiefling taking the magic initiate feat at L4 would have an additional three cantrips for a total of five.  They would get thaumaturgy from their racial feature and an additional two cantrips from the feat.

### Classes granting cantrips at 1st level

Wizard, sorcerer, cleric, druid, bard, warlock all grant cantrips:

> At 1st level, you know two cantrips of your choice from the [*class*] spell list

### Feats

Some feats grant additional cantrips known: aberrant dragon mark, spell sniper, and magic initiate.

### Racial Features

Some races have a feature that grants a cantrip.  E.g. the [Infernal Legacy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/tiefling#TieflingTraits) trait of the tiefling:

> You know the thaumaturgy cantrip.

### Maximum cantrips innate to the character: 33

The following build uses a racial features, feats, and a ludicrous amount of multiclassing to maximize the number of cantrips known for a "level 4 eldritch knight."  The build only gets two classes to level 4, thus only gets two feats.

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Level} & \textbf{Cantrips} \\ \hline
  \text{bard} & \text{1} & \text{2} \\ \hline
  \text{cleric} & \text{1} & \text{2} \\ \hline
  \text{druid} & \text{1} & \text{2} \\ \hline
  \text{sorc} & \text{4} & \text{5} \\ \hline
  \text{wizard} & \text{2 illusion tradition} & \text{3+1} \\ \hline
  \text{warlock celestial} & \text{3 pact of the tome} & \text{4+3} \\ \hline
  \text{rogue} & \text{3 arcane trickster} & \text{0+3} \\ \hline
  \text{artificer} & \text{1} & \text{2} \\ \hline
  \text{fighter} & \text{4 eldritch knight} & \text{0+2} \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \textbf{total} & \text{20} & \text{29} \\ \hline
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
  \textbf{Feat or Feature} & \textbf{Cantrips} \\ \hline
  \text{Racial Feature e.g. Infernal Legacy} & \text{1} \\ \hline
  \text{Spell Sniper or Aberrant Dragon Mark feats} & \text{1} \\ \hline
  \text{Magic Initiate feat} & \text{2} \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \textbf{total} & \text{4}  \\ \hline
\end{array}

**Grand total of 33 cantrips known at level 20.**

### Interesting honorary mention: Mizzium Apparatus

This is a wondrous item described in Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica on page 179 that allows the wearer to attempt to cast cantrips on their class list despite not knowing them with a DC10 arcana check.  Coupled with rogue's expertise and a decent int bonus, it would allow reasonably reliable casting any cantrip from the character's class lists.

### Sauces:

- Celestial Warlock is from Xanathar's Guide to Everything p.54
- Aberrant Dragonmark is from Eberron: Rising from the Last War p.52
- Artificer class is from Eberron: Rising from the Last War p.55
- Mizzium Apparatus is from Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica p.179

Comment: Do the Ravnica backgrounds grant cantrips?

Comment: @Medix2 ooo... that's a good point. I didn't think to check there.  Also, eberron artificer might get cantrips.  I haven't used that source book enough yet.

Comment: @Medix2 Flipping through it appears the backgrounds add cantrips to your spell list, but don't grant them to you directly.  Interestingly there is an item that lets the user cast cantrips they don't know, but are on their class list.

Comment: Celestial Warlock starts with 4 cantrips.

Comment: Don't forget, High Elves get any Wizard cantrip. Also, why did you mention multiclassing with *Magic Initiate*? In regards to number of cantrips known, it's strictly better than *Spell Sniper*.

Comment: @RevenantBacon good point about magic initiate.  I'll update that.  There are a number of races that can get a cantrip.  I figured tiefling was a decent example as it's in the basic rules.

Comment: @GcL There are only three races in the PHB that give cantrips, Forest Gnomes, High Elves, and the Tieflings. You're already listing all of the classes and feats that grant cantrips and how many they grant, I don't know why you wouldn't do the same with races as well. Oh, and also if our Celestial Warlock selects *Pact of the Tome*, that's another 3 cantrips known, from any list.

Comment: @RevenantBacon there are a number of racial variants in the Eberron expansion that grant a cantrip.  Pact of the Tome!  good catch.

Comment: @GcL I don't actually have the Eberron book, so I don't actually know what's in there. I only brought up the High Elf and the Gnome because they're in the PHB (And the elf option is strictly better :p ) Pact of the Tome is actually really good too, because if you pump Warlock to 4 and drop Arcane Trickster, you net one extra cantrip (3 base Warlock level 4, 2 Celestial, 3 Tome), AND one more ASI.